Convert a C# .NET Framework 4.8 project (containing references to Microsoft.VisualBasic) to .NET Core 8.0 project
I have a C# project targeted at .NET Framework 4.8 and I want to convert it to a .NET Core 8.0 project. I've used the Microsoft Upgrade tool and it has coverted it but it has problems with references to Microsoft.VisualBasic which are in the orginal project.
Specically :
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices; //Does not exist
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices;             //Does not exist
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging;             //Does not exist
ApplicationBase                                  //Does not exist
using System.Data.sqlClient;                     //Does not exist
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.MyServices.Internal; //Does not exist

Whereas :
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices;    //Does exist

There are other issues but if I can get these sorted I think I'll be well on my way to getting project converted.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks.
Regards,
Jim.
Here is the code from a miminal project. It has 2 classes Class1.cs and MyProject.cs :
Class1.cs :
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices;

namespace DotNetFramework4._8.My
{
    [StandardModule]
    [OptionText]
    [HideModuleName]
    public sealed class MyWebExtension
    {
        private static MyProject.ThreadSafeObjectProvider<WebUser> s_User = new MyProject.ThreadSafeObjectProvider<WebUser>();
    }
}

MyProject.cs :
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.MyServices.Internal;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace DotNetFramework4._8.My
{
    [HideModuleName]
    [StandardModule]
    [GeneratedCode("MyTemplate", "8.0.0.0")]
    internal sealed class MyProject
    {
        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        [ComVisible(false)]
        internal sealed class ThreadSafeObjectProvider<T> where T : new()
        {
            private readonly ContextValue<T> m_Context;

            internal T GetInstance
            {
                [DebuggerHidden]
                get
                {
                    T getInstance = this.m_Context.Value;
                    if ((object)getInstance == null)
                    {
                        getInstance = new T();
                        this.m_Context.Value = getInstance;
                    }
                    return getInstance;
                }
            }

            [DebuggerHidden]
            [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
            public ThreadSafeObjectProvider() => this.m_Context = new ContextValue<T>();
        }
    }
}

Just create targeted at .NET Framework 4.8 and it should compile error free you will have to references to Microsoft.VisualBasic, perhaps add it as NuGet package.
Then try converting to .NET Core 8.0 the Microsoft.VisualBasic references are no longer available. I want to find an equivalent.
I've found a Microsoft page which says : "If your code depends on the use of Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices types and their members, you may be able to use a corresponding type or member in the .NET class library. For example, some System.Environment and System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity members provide equivalent functionality to the properties of the Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.User class." it's found here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/visualbasic
Thanks,
Jim.

It depends on how you are using those namespaces.

Not sure about the VB resources but there is a Microsoft SqlClient library to use instead. I believe the 'System' library relied on windows and now in a cross platform environment you cant lean on windows os to have those things

Add the package for "Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices", via nuget, search it, and add it:  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualBasic/10.3.0  ?

Okay this line of code work in the original project :
private static MyProject.ThreadSafeObjectProvider<WebUser> s_User = new MyProject.ThreadSafeObjectProvider<WebUser>();

Where you see WebUser read Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WebUser but that's not available in .NET Core

Microsoft say that : System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity  provides equivalent functionality but I can't work out how to use it!

need a [mre], with just error messages solving this is hard....

Luuk I already have the CompilerServices! It's ApplicationServices, Devices & Logging that are missing.

How do I upload a sample project to this forum?

Hi btolsen131, yes I was able to find replacement sqlClient resources. Thanks.

Luuk, I've written a minimal project but it's still to much to cut & paste into a comment!
It has 2 classes Class1.cs & MyProject.cs. Here is Class1.cs :
`using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices;
namespace DotNetFramework4._8.My
{
[StandardModule]
[OptionText]
[HideModuleName]
public sealed class MyWebExtension
{
private static MyProject.ThreadSafeObjectProvider s_User = new MyProject.ThreadSafeObjectProvider();
}
}`

That didn't format very well I'm sorry!
